# error creating container in openstack swift

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

I am trying to install the latest version of `swift` following instructions from http://docs.openstack.org/icehouse/install.../general-installation-steps-swift.html. I am able to authenticate with keystone and also able to successfully run the command `swift stat`. But, when I run the command `swift upload myfiles temp`, I get the following error

```
Error trying to create container 'myfiles': 404 Not Found: {"error": {"message": "The 
resource could not be found.", "c
Object PUT failed: 9.109.124.109:5000:5000/v2.0/myfiles/temp 400 Bad Request 
[first 60 chars of response] {"error": {"message": "Expecting to find application/json 
in
```

In `/var/log/syslog`, I find the following information:

```
May 28 18:11:40 datafed3 account-server: ERROR __call__ error with PUT /sdb1/100869
/AUTH_system/myfiles : #012Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "/usr/lib
/python2.7/dist-packages/swift/account/server.py", line 284, in __call__#012    res = 
method(req)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/swift/common/utils.py", line 
2217, in wrapped#012    return func(*a, **kw)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/swift/common/utils.py", line 837, in _timing_stats#012    resp = func(ctrl, 
*args, **kwargs)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/swift/account/server.py", 
line 128, in PUT#012    req.headers['x-bytes-used'])#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/swift/account/backend.py", line 210, in put_container#012    raise 
DatabaseConnectionError(self.db_file, "DB doesn't exist")#012DatabaseConnectionError: 
DB connection error (/srv/node/sdb1/accounts/100869/80d/62816079be0fc97a4557f52b3b12380d
/62816079be0fc97a4557f52b3b12380d.db, 0):#012DB doesn't exist
```

Comment: you have problem with your database connection.
May be you purged the Database, or you can have problem with partitioning.(I am just guessing)

Comment: I reinstalled and now, everything works fine. In any case, do you know how to fix the problem?

Comment: Generally, swift does not throw database error. Something else, may affect the database. Most probably you will not face this exception any more,hopefully. If you are familiar with swift, it always gives different types of errors. I have installed swift hundred times, every time I face different errors. This is the nature of Swift, unfortunately :)

Answer (score 0):

One situation may cause this problem is: when create tenant, one or more storage node is down. then when you upload an object, proxy get 404 from at least one storage node.
On my test, even the storage node are all up after tenant creation, 404 error still exist. So, make sure all storage nodes are up, and create another tenant to test.